# How do I target only the x64 version of a nuget package using centrally managed Nuget package versions?

Tags: c#, nuget

We have a large solution (~400 C# projects) and are attempting to change the solution to use [centralized package version management](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Centrally-managing-NuGet-package-versions) because things are quite messy. The final issue we need to address is a compilation error when referencing a specific multi-platform Nuget package ([CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore) and its ultimate dependency [chromiumembeddedframework.runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/chromiumembeddedframework.runtime) `Directory.Packages.Props` file this way:

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageVersion Include="CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore" Version="109.1.110" />
    <PackageVersion Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime" Version="109.1.11" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

The project includes a package reference specified as:

```
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore" />
<PackageReference Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime" />
```

Note that we've tried referencing only CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore as well as the full chain of dependencies to Chromium Embedded Framework (CefSharp.Common.NetCore is in the middle). We have also tried referencing the specific CEF for the platform we are targeting (x64).

The project is targeting `x64`, so we have tried adding all of the target-specific dependencies and still have the error:

`NU1008 Projects that use central package version management should not define the version on the PackageReference items but on the PackageVersion items: chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-arm64;chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-x86.`

It appears that packages for other architectures are being added in at compile time and the build won't complete.

**Minimal Example**
Using Visual Studio 2022 solution I can reproduce this problem with no code.

A simple project along with a directory.packages.props and a nuget.config (nuget.config is auto-generated) show it neatly.
Project.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

directory.packages.props

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
    <CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>true</CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageVersion Include="CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore" Version="109.1.110" />
    <PackageVersion Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime" Version="109.1.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Edit 1**: the original issue only appeared to occur with the temporary project created for compiling XAML and since it had to do with package references my initial attempts to resolve it centered around the `IncludePackageReferencesDuringMarkupCompilation` property. This is not the case. The initial answers were for this problem but they made it clear I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: If you set the "IncludePackageReferencesDuringMarkupCompilation" property to "false" in a C# project, the compiler won't include any package reference assemblies in the final output. This means that any external package dependencies listed in the "packages.config" file won't be in the compiled output. This can make the output files smaller, but you'll need to separately deploy and reference the dependencies at runtime for the app to run properly.

Comment: @jazb thanks, that is helpful. I think it helps me realize I'm asking the wrong question as that doesn't seem to have anything to do with packages not in the original project being added to the temporary project. I kept digging and it seems that something about the build process is adding the ARM64 and x86 packages for the chromium embedded framework. 

Not at all related to your answer, but I have worked around the problem by adding an x64 package condition to both the CefSharp and chromium packages since we're only building for an x64 target anyway.

Edit: spoke too soon. Still an issue.

Comment: Since the error message is about a package on nuget.org, can you create a sample project or solution that reproduces the error?

Comment: @zivkan I changed the question and added detail for a minimal sample project. At this point I think I might have resolved the issue (not to my satisfaction) by referencing all of the platform versions explicitly rather than waiting for the tools to try to add them. I'm not certain if it's a bug or just an annoying feature at play between Nuget and the centrally managed nuget version feature. I'll post an answer after I figure out which it is and maybe this will save somebody else a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I have worked around this issue by explicitly adding all of the dependencies (for every target platform) to both the `directory.packages.props` file and the `csproj` file. Because I don't actually want the output to contain any dependencies other than x64 I have marked the other target platform dependencies as private so msbuild does not include them in the outputs.

So, for my project that relies on `CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore` (which ultimately relies on the `chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-x64`) I have this grouping of `PackageReference` elements:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore" />
<PackageReference Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime" />
<PackageReference Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-x64" />
<PackageReference Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-x86">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-arm64">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

This solves the problem of the build failure and the problem in Visual Studio where the project package dependencies would constantly cycle from valid to invalid and back again. It also does not have the down side of including binaries I don't want in the build output. However, it seems like a bit of a hacky workaround.

**Edit:** The problem appears to be related to discussion [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11967) and is because of the PackageReference elements in the `buildTransitive/CefSharp.Common.NETCore.targets` file (part of the `CefSharp.Common.NETCore.nupkg`). Might have to stick with the workaround.